# Update a Textview in a ViewPager by normal java class

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager, layout-inflater

I use the ViewPager from the compatibility pack to page fragments.
I want to have a background service which serves the fragments with data. Therefore I use a "normal java class" to update (for example) a TextView in such a fragment:

```
public class Updater {

 private Activity mActivity=null;
 private TextView tv = null;
 private Context mContext; 
 private View mInflatedMenu =null;

 public Updater (Activity _activity, Context _context, View inflatedMenu) { 
    mActivity = _activity;
    mContext = _context;
    mInflatedMenu = inflatedMenu;
 }

 public void updateTextView (String _text) {
    tv = (TextView) mInflatedMenu.findViewById(R.id.tvFragment1Updater);
    tv.setText(_text);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }      

}
```

The Toast says, that the TextView has the value of the parameter `_text`. That's okay!
The problem: On the screen the original value of the TextView hasn't changed to `_text`.

I think I've tried all kinds of `invalidate()`. What I'm doing wrong? How would you update your fragment "views" in a ViewPager?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the toast instance, when you are changing the vlaue of `_text`, you neen to hide the old toast and create a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think my question was not really clear. The toast instance is only a "helping function" to check that the value has "internally" has changed, but is not refreshed on the view. Maybe you can help me again?

Comment: setText() does not require any kind of invalidation, your problem is some place else, try to see if you are not changing his value back to some thing else, and that he is the view that is currently shown